# sitemaps in Zend 1.12.3 after https

Tags: php, zend-framework, https

I recently turn on the https on my website, but since that my sitemaps are not working anymore (in google console: sitemaps are html files..).

Now everytime i try to access the sitemaps.xml it take me to index page.

After i notice that, i also notice that in the sitemap.php file (in the root directory of my site), my website url were still in http, but after changing that it still the same.

Maybe i need to change url in an other file necessary for the sitemaps but i didn't find any.

Someone already get this problem ?